# How to fix this common problem of position:fixed elements not expanding to its parent width?

Tags: css, expand, css-position

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4VS7/

How do I make the yellow element align (horz) with the grey background no matter how the window is resized? I refuse to believe it can't be done with css. Yes, js hacks and Scroll Follow plugin works but lags.

Please, anyone?

*Edit:*

*Found a solution. If the container margins are expressed as percentages the content part can be expressed as the remainder percentage. See here:* http://jsfiddle.net/h4VS7/1/

*Though not sure why it doesn't align perfectly. It should I think. Could be jsfiddle margin/padding related.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not particularly difficult if you don't mind adding an extra element to wrap `.top`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ud3ZQ/

---

And also, a properly aligning (well, almost) version of your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/h4VS7/3/

The problem was that jsFiddle loads http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/result-light.css:

```
body {background: white; padding: 10px;  }
```

Anything is more specific than `*` (including `body`), so the `padding` was being applied, regardless of `* {padding:0; margin:0}`